OnHit function is not called
I am new to Unreal Engine and am trying to make projectiles fired disappear after hitting something and apply impulse to it if the physics can be generated on that object. I am using Unreal 4.27.
Following the tutorial by my teacher I created an object channel "Projectile" with deafult block response. Following is the code snippet I seem to have a problem with:
void AProjectile::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    CollisionComponent->BodyInstance.SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Projectile"));
    CollisionComponent->OnComponentHit.AddDynamic(this, &AProjectile::OnHit);
}

///

void AProjectile::OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComponent, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit) 
{

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("onhitstarted"));
    static const float Impulse = 100.0f;

    if (OtherActor != this && OtherComponent->IsSimulatingPhysics()) 
    {
        OtherComponent->AddImpulseAtLocation(ProjectileMovementComponent->Velocity * Impulse, Hit.ImpactPoint);
    }

    if(IsPendingKill())
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("is going to be destroyed"));
    //ProjectileMovementComponent->StopMovementImmediately();
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DESTROYED"));
    Destroy();
}

I have turned on Generating OnHitCollisions both in the blueprint I am using as a bullet and in the staticMeshObject I am trying to test this on. CollisionComponent is a USphereComponent. Closing UnrealEditor, building the project and opening it again did not work, as did not recompiling.
